# C# observable collection

Tags: c#, observablecollection

Does anyone know can i retrieve the first element of an observation collection?

I have already added elements to my collection:

```
 _fetchingWords.Add(new Words { English = "abc", French = "dcb", Spanish = "mez"});
```

I need to retrieve the first element ,ie , abc .

Comment: What is `Words`? A simply class with properties?

Comment: `var first = _fetchingWords[0]` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use linq,

```
var firstElement = _fetchingWords.First();
```

Answer (score 0):

ObservableCollection has an [index](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132434(v=vs.110).aspx)
It is as simple as
I take it English is a property

```
_fetchingWords[_fetchingWords.Count - 1].English;
```